# Angular 4 not updating navbar after login - stuck on redux

Tags: angular

As you can see by the code below, I have tried everything that I could think of and I have tried everything that I have read, but the ngIf within the navbar is not being updated.

As you can see with the service file, the console shows the variables of loggedIn and adminLoggedIn are being updated after login, but the console.log that are being called from within the navbar are not writing anything after login, only on init. It's like they are being called on init, but never again.

As a result, I have tried to use BehavoirSubject, which I do not quite understand, but async is not working after login with the variable mLoggedIn$ or the function isLoggedIn.

Basically what I am trying to accomplish, is to have the login and register buttons go away after login, along with having the "More" menu appear when they are logged in, followed by only showing the admin buttons to users who have isAdmin set to "1" from the db.

BTW, most of the examples that I have seen use auth guard, but I am using a PHP api and MySQL

With that said, the following is my services:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ShoppingCartValuesService {
  private mLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(
    false
  );
  public shoppingCartValues = "n";
  public loginObj: any;
  public uri = "<path to some php file>";
  public loggedIn: any;
  public adminLoggedIn: any;

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.mLoggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.loginObj = new Observable(() => {
      this.loginObj = {
        uName: "",
        isAdmin: "",
        ts: ""
      };
    });
    this.loggedIn = new Observable(() => {
      this.loggedIn = false;
      console.log("loggedIn: ", this.loggedIn);
    });
    this.adminLoggedIn = new Observable(() => {
      this.adminLoggedIn = false;
      console.log("adminLoggedIn: ", this.adminLoggedIn);
    });
  }

  getLogin(email, password) {
    return new Observable(observe => {
      this.http
        .get(this.uri + "?name=" + email + "&pass1=" + password)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.loginObj = res;
          if (this.loginObj.uName) {
            this.loggedIn = true;
            this.mLoggedIn.next(true);
          }
          if (this.loginObj.isAdmin === "1") {
            this.adminLoggedIn = true;
            this.mLoggedIn.next(true);
          } else {
            console.log(
              "this is not an admin account this.adminLoggedIn: " +
                this.adminLoggedIn +
                " this.loggedIn: " +
                this.loggedIn
            );
          }
          observe.next(res);
          this.router.navigate(["/"]);
        });
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.mLoggedIn.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
  }
}
```

The following is my login component:

```
import { ShoppingCartValuesService } from "../shopping-cart-values.service";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.css"]
})
export class LoginComponent {
  public Obj: any;
  email = "";
  password = "";
  constructor(private srvc: ShoppingCartValuesService) {}

  login() {
    this.srvc.getLogin(this.email, this.password).subscribe(result => {
      this.Obj = result;
      console.log("this obj returned: ", this.Obj);
    });
  }
}
```

The following is my navbar component, which is not updating after login:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar navbar-light sticky-top">
  <a
    id="home"
    class="navbar-brand"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    title="Home"
    routerLink="/"
    ><span>Home</span></a
  >
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    (click)="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed"
    [attr.aria-expanded]="!navbarCollapsed"
    type="button"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
    aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div
    class="collapse navbar-collapse"
    [ngbCollapse]="navbarCollapsed"
    id="navbarsExampleDefault"
  >
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          data-toggle="tooltip"
          title="Products"
          routerLink="/products"
          id="products"
          ><span>Products</span></a
        >
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          data-toggle="tooltip"
          title="Shopping cart"
          id="shopping-cart-0"
          routerLink="/shopping-cart"
          ><span>Shopping Cart</span></a
        >
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="!mIsLoggedIn" class="nav-item">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          data-toggle="tooltip"
          title="Register"
          id="register"
          routerLink="/register"
          ><span>Register</span></a
        >
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="!mIsLoggedIn" class="nav-item">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          data-toggle="tooltip"
          title="Login"
          routerLink="/login"
          id="login-btn"
          ><span>Login</span></a
        >
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="!mIsLoggedIn" ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a
          ngbDropdownToggle
          class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
          href="//:javascript"
          id="dropdown01"
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"
          >More</a
        >
        <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a
            class="dropdown-item"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            title="My orders"
            routerLink="/my-orders"
            id="search-records"
            ><span>Search Records</span></a
          >
          <a
            *ngIf="adminLoggedIn"
            class="dropdown-item"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            title="Admin search records"
            routerLink="/admin/orders"
            id="admin-search-records"
            ><span>Admin Search Records</span></a
          >
          <a
            *ngIf="adminLoggedIn"
            class="dropdown-item"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            title="Admin products"
            routerLink="/admin/products"
            id="admin-products"
            ><span>Admin Products</span></a
          >
          <a
            class="dropdown-item"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            title="Log out"
            routerLink="/"
            id="logout-btn"
            ><span>Logout</span></a
          >
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

One other thing - zero errors and zero warnings. The only thing in the console are the console.logs from the initial settings and the console.logs from the services after login show the values have changed.

I hope you can help, because this should be working. I know that I am missing something trivial.

After reading several articles, I have determined that redux was the only way to go, but now I am stuck.

The following is my reducer:

```
import { ACTION_LOGOUT, ACTION_LOGIN } from "./../actions/appActions";

export interface AppReducerState {
  loggedIn: boolean;
  uName: string;
  isAdmin: number;
}

export const initialState: AppReducerState = {
  loggedIn: false,
  uName: "Guest",
  isAdmin: 0
};

export function reducers(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action) {
    case ACTION_LOGOUT:
      return {
        login: false
      };
    case ACTION_LOGIN:
      return {
        login: true
      };
  }
  return state;
}

export const login = (state: AppReducerState) => state.loggedIn;
```

Within my services file, I added the following function:

```
getState() {
  return this.store.select(ACTION_LOGIN);
}
```

Within my bs-navbar component, I init the call to getState:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.srvc.getState().subscribe(state => {
    console.log(state);
  });
}
```

However, the console shows undefined.

Revamped bs-navbar component:

```
import { ShoppingCartValuesService } from "../shopping-cart-values.service";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-bs-navbar",
  templateUrl: "./bs-navbar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./bs-navbar.component.css"]
})
export class BsNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public loginObj: any;
  shoppingCartCounter = 0;
  shoppingCart = "shopping-cart-0";
  constructor(private srvc: ShoppingCartValuesService) {
    this.loginObj = {
      uName: "",
      isAdmin: "0",
      ts: "",
      loggedIn: false
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.srvc.getState().subscribe(state => {
      console.log(state);
    });
  }

  onLogin() {
    this.loginObj.loggedIn = this.srvc.loginObj.subscribe(res => {
      this.loginObj.loggedIn = res;
    });
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.srvc.logout();
  }
}
```

Revamped services:

```
import { ACTION_LOGIN } from "./store/actions/appActions";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ShoppingCartValuesService {
  public shoppingCartValues = "n";
  public loginObj: any;
  public uri = "http://local.kronus:8001/v2018/assets/api/send_get.pdo.php";

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<any>
  ) {
    this.loginObj = new Observable(() => {
      this.loginObj = {
        uName: "",
        isAdmin: "0",
        ts: "",
        loggedIn: false
      };
    });
  }

  getLogin(email, password) {
    return new Observable(observe => {
      this.http
        .get(this.uri + "?name=" + email + "&pass1=" + password)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.loginObj = res;
          if (this.loginObj.uName != null) {
            this.loginObj.loggedIn = true;
          }
          if (this.loginObj.isAdmin === "1") {
          } else {
            console.log(
              "from srvc this is not an admin account this.loginObj.adminLoggedIn: " +
                this.loginObj.isAdmin +
                " from srvc this.loginObj.loggedIn: " +
                this.loginObj.loggedIn
            );
          }
          observe.next(res);
          this.router.navigate(["/"]);
        });
    });
  }

    getState() {
      return this.store.select(ACTION_LOGIN);
    }

  logout() {
    this.loginObj.loggedIn = false;
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
  }
}
```

Revamped login component:

```
import { ShoppingCartValuesService } from "../shopping-cart-values.service";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.css"]
})
export class LoginComponent {
  public loginObj: any;
  email = "";
  password = "";
  constructor(private srvc: ShoppingCartValuesService) {
    this.loginObj = new Observable(() => {
      this.loginObj = {
        uName: "",
        isAdmin: "0",
        ts: "",
        loggedIn: false
      };
    });
  }

  login() {
    this.srvc.getLogin(this.email, this.password).subscribe(result => {
      this.loginObj = result;
      this.loginObj.loggedIn = this.srvc.loginObj.loggedIn;
      this.loginObj.isAdmin = this.srvc.loginObj.isAdmin;
      console.log("this loginObj from login returned: ", this.loginObj);
    });
  }
}
```

Also, if anyone knows of a simple Angular 6 Redux tutorial, then please let me know and thanks in advance

Comment: `mLoggedIn` and `adminLoggedIn` are properties of your service and they don't exist in your component. You can access them using `srvc.mLoggedIn` in the component. But that might not be the only problem. If `mLoggedIn`/`adminLoggedIn` are observables or subjects you need `async` pipe to get the value. And if it still doesn't work then check your `getLogin` method that subscribes to `http.get` in the observer. I don't think that's the right way to use observables. Try simplifying your code and your example, it will help you find the issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Are you talking about the line <li *ngIf="!mIsLoggedIn" class="nav-item">? I don't see any reference to mIsLoggedIn in the component class, how will the html template know about it (forgive me, I am just used to Reactive Forms approach, so my question may be invalid too.).  how about declaring variable mIsLoggedIn in your component, then populating it when you receive data from your getLogin(). sth like  this.srvc.getLogin(this.email, this.password).subscribe(result => { this.mIsLoggedIn = result.isLoggedIn; }

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE after comment conversation with OP:

Here is what I would do:

```
// in your LoginComponent

// initialize your Obj that you will be using in HTML and provide default/initial value
public Obj: any = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  isAdmin: 0 // using 0 because thats what your response object from getLogin returns.
};

this.srvc.getLogin(this.email, this.password).subscribe(result => {
  this.Obj.isLoggedIn = result.loggedIn;
  this.Obj.isAdmin = result.isAdmin;})

// now in your html, where ever you have mIsLoggedIn and adminLoggedIn,
// replace with Obj.isLoggedIn and Obj.isAdmin respectively
```

Hope this helps... it seems to me that you problem may be with not using the correct property when binding in html.

You have not declared `mLoggedIn` and `adminLoggedIn` variables in your `LoginComponent`. Without declaring the variables in the `component class`, HTML template won't know about it.

How about you try adding the two variables `mLoggedIn` and `adminLoggedIn` in `LoginComponent` and populate/update them after you have received the data from you `getLogin` call? Something like:

```
this.srvc.getLogin(this.email, this.password)
         .subscribe(result => { this.mIsLoggedIn = result.loggedIn;
                                this.adminLoggedIn = result.adminLoggedIn; })
```

OR you could assign the result to your `Obj` as you are currently doing and update the `html templates` to use

```
<li *ngIf="!Obj.loggedIn" class="nav-item"> and
<a *ngIf="Obj.adminLoggedIn"...>
```

If the approach works, please be sure to delete those unused `mIsLoggedIn` from service class. Otherwise, it will very likely be a source of confusion later.

Comment: thank you for replying. I have tried your suggestion of this.mIsLoggedIn = result.loggedIn; but I receive an compilation error 'loggedIn' does not exist as type {} - I tried it anyway with the same result. I have also tried this.mIsLoggedIn$ = this.srvc.loggedIn; which has no compilation errors, but does not work either. When I try ngIf="Obj.uName" in the html, then I receive the following error in the console - TypeError: "_co.Obj is undefined" - I assume this because Obj is not set until after receiving data during the login process

Comment: BTW, if I were to place it in the nav component, then how would I do that? It is called from login() in the login component currently, but is there some way to place these variables to call the results from service

Comment: Lets start by seeing what is being returned by your getLogin method in your component? can you console.log whats being returned and what properties it has? As for the undefined error, yes it is because you haven't initialized your Obj in component class. In your component class, you should give initial value so the template doesn't throw error; public Obj: any = {mIsLoggedin: false, admin: false}}

Comment: initializing loginObj.isAdmin & loginObj.loggedIn - the following are the console results: this loginObj.loggedIn from navbar ngoninit returned:  false this loginObj.isAdmin from navbar ngoninit returned:  0 from srvc this is not an admin account this.loginObj.adminLoggedIn: 0 from srvc this.loginObj.loggedIn: true this loginObj from login returned:  
Object { id: "1", uName: "tarik18",(", isAdmin: "0", ts: "2018-12-24 16:56:49", loggedIn: true } *ngIf="!(loginObj.loggedIn | async) as loggedIn" - still same result - register & login buttons still appear after login

Comment: so you are getting data back correctly, then it has to be a problem with binding. My first guess was that you may be using incorrect property but if there isn't any error in the console that may not be the case. I updated the answer, can you see if that helps?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I have done, with the exception that I used loginObj, instead of Obj. There is some additional good news to the progress of these changes - in the console for the html after login - I am seeing <!--bindings="ng-reflect-ng-if": "true" }--> Since I am using *ngIf="!loginObj.loggedIn" this means that li should no longer be there, correct? Do think this is because the icon is a background-image to the anchor tag within the li and that is why it still appears to be visible?

Comment: Since you are using *ngIf directive on the <li> node, I would expect entire of li with its child nodes to appear/disappear. I am not sure about the second part. I dont think it should matter but I haven't encountered that scenario. I am really curious what the issue is. I can't think of any other suggestion. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185797/discussion-between-nosaidthecompiler-and-kronus).